# Null cursor return

Tags: java, android

Im attempting to develop an android program that has a user select an item from a listmenu......then pass the ID of this item to an intent to a second class, the ID is then stored in a variable and is inputted into a DBhelper method to get the name and age of a person and display this data in their relevant EditTexts in the XML.

Everything works fine until I try to start the second intent. Im getting a error of:

```
01-11 22:21:28.448: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqliteexample/com.example.sqliteexample.DisplayContents}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

Note that I have initialized the 'id' variable passed with '0'. this isn't being passed to the class methods to get the name and age?

Hopefully someone can give me a push in the right direction.

again

Here's my code. 2 method in my DB helper class to get the name and age from the DB:

```
public String showData(long id) {

        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            // move to the selected row
        c.moveToFirst();
        String namePass = c.getString(1);
        return namePass;
        }
        return null;

        }

    public String showAge(long id) {

        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null)
        {
            // move to the selected row
        c.moveToFirst();
        String agePass = c.getString(2);
        return agePass;
        }
        return null;
```

Class for the listview, passing the id variable and starting the intent:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int list_posistion, long item_id)
{


    long id = item_id;
    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.sqliteexample.DisplayContents");
    i.putExtra("passID", id);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Last class which opens from the intent and displays the name and age on the onCreate:

```
package com.example.sqliteexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

public class DisplayContents extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.displaycontents);

long id = 0;
EditText namePassed;
EditText agePassed;

namePassed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameShow);
agePassed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageShow);
HotOrNot display = new HotOrNot(this, null, null);


    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    if (extras != null) {
        id = extras.getLong("passedID"); 
    }
    display.open();
    String returnedName = display.showData(id);
    String returnedAge  = display.showAge(id);

    namePassed.setText(returnedName);
    agePassed.setText(returnedAge);
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you implement the pattern posted by Eric. If you for some unexpected reason can't find a match in your database for the given id, your application will crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you spot your error?

```
 i.putExtra("passID", id);
 id = extras.getLong("passedID");
```

It can be wise to store `Extra`-names as constants to eliminate typos

Comment: This is probably the correct answer; I just thought I would add: The OP should probably also use `if (c.getCount() > 0)` or check the `boolean` value returned from `.moveToFirst()` to make sure there *is* data before attempting to retrieve it.

Comment: @Eric Excellent point! I can't recall what `query()` returns if no entries was found in the database. If it's an empty `Cursor`, OPs `if(c != null)` will be useless, and your solution would prevent the `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Yes, it's an empty `Cursor`, so checking the row count (or result from `.moveToFirst()`) is the best way to check if there's content. I believe `.query()` returns `null` only if there is an error.

Comment: @Eric Ahh.. of course. Haven't written database-code in ages. You should post your solution as an answer, as it is the correct one! :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Ole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742660/ole)'s comment about the extras, you may find that you come in contact with boundary exceptions in the event that you are given an empty `Cursor` (that is, one with zero rows—which you are getting, since your ID is not correct).

In order to prevent this, it is best to check either A) the number of rows in the cursor, or B) the result of any `.move*()` operations.

If you anticipate only one row (like looking up from a unique ID), then the following will suffice:

```
Cursor c = someDatabase.query(...);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) { // null check (if error), and valid row check
    // Your row operation
}
```

Otherwise, for multiple rows, you will need another methodology (there are lots, this is a fairly straightforward one):

```
Cursor c = someDatabase.query(...);
if (c != null) { // Will hit if there is an error
    if (c.moveToFirst()) { // If we have rows
        do {
            // Your row operation
        } while (c.moveToNext()); // Step into next row
    }
}
```